# How can I dynamically format an input element in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am using angular2, the new forms api.

I want to have a phone number input box, which is auto-formatted as the user types.

For example the user types:

```
12345678901
```

and as they enter a recognizable phone number it changes to

```
1 (234) 567-8901
```

I figured out how to add a directive onto the input control but I don't know how to inject myself into the input processing pipeline.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to create your own directive, take this one as an example, it transforms using Phone.format, storing the raw number in the model but displaying the formatted number to the user:

```js
import { Directive } from '@angular/core'
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms'
import { Phone } from '../phone'

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][phone]',
  host: {
    '(ngModelChange)': 'onInputChange($event)',
    '(blur)': 'onBlur($event)'
  }
})
export class PhoneDirective {

  constructor (control: NgControl) {
    this.control = control
  }

  ngOnInit () {
    let formatted = Phone.format(this.control.model)
    setTimeout(() => this.control.valueAccessor.writeValue(formatted), 0)
  }

  onBlur () {
    let val = this.control.model
    let raw = val.replace(/\W/g, '')
    let formatted = Phone.format(raw)

    this.control.valueAccessor.writeValue(formatted)
    this.control.viewToModelUpdate(raw)
  }

  onInputChange (val) {
    let raw = val.replace(/\W/g, '')
    if (val !== raw) this.control.viewToModelUpdate(raw)
  }
}
```

Comment: seems you are using angular2 beta for your code, PS: `angular2/core` has been changed with `@angular/core` etc.

Comment: btw i dont think this one is answer as per question.

Comment: I updated it with the latest forms code. It was pretty close, needed `NgControl` instead and `(ngModelChange)` event. Also it had a re-entrant update which infinite looped.

Comment: Im still having a problem where the formatting isn't happening when the directive is first launched. I tried using `ngOnInit` to get the `this.control.value` but it's always null. I'm not sure at what point the value gets initialized into the control.

Comment: Ok I basically figured out that you can use the `this.control.model` property in `ngOnInit`. However, you have to do it in `setTimeout` otherwise something else writes the value to the valueAccessor after this runs. Not sure if there is a cleaner way.

Comment: It works pretty well except that if you're editing in the middle it messes up your cursor position ... so that sucks.

Comment: Ok it works better to update the model value in `blur` than in the input change event. I am also setting the raw unformatted number into the model but displaying the formatted version to the user. This is the final form for this question, I upvoted and marked as correct. Thanks for the pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

The directive below will format the value as you type:

1. the `input` method is triggered when the user enters the value (view -> model, aka $parser in AngularJS). It makes sure the view gets formatted view (via `render` method) while the model gets raw numeric value (via `propagateChange` method).
2. the `writeValue` method is triggered when the model is updated (model -> view, aka $formatter in AngularJS). It makes sure the view gets formatted view (via `render` method).
3. the `format` method contains the logic to format the view. We need some extra conditions there to make sure the user can not only input characters but also remove them one by one.

To use the directive register it in the module and link it to the input, e.g.:

`<input appFormattedNumber formControlName= .../>`

(I have tested this with reactive forms only)

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, forwardRef, HostListener, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFormattedNumber]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => FormattedNumberDirective),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class FormattedNumberDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {
  propagateChange;

  constructor( private renderer: Renderer2, private element: ElementRef ) {}

  @HostListener('input', [ '$event.target.value' ])
  input( value ) {
    const canonical = this.removeNonNumericCharacters(value);

    const formatted = this.format(canonical);
    this.render(formatted);

    this.propagateChange(canonical);
  }
  writeValue( value: any ): void {
    const canonical = this.removeNonNumericCharacters(value.toString());
    const formatted = this.format(canonical);
    this.render(formatted);
  }

  registerOnChange( fn: any ): void {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {}

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {}

  private removeNonNumericCharacters(value): string {
    return value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  }

  private format(value): string {
    if (value.length < 5) {
      return value;
    }

    const int = value.substring(0, 1);
    const areaCode = value.substring(1, 4);
    const ext1 = value.substring(4, 7);
    const ext2 = value.substring(7, 11);
    const ext = ext2 ? ` ${ext1}-${ext2}` : `${ext1}`;

    return `${int} (${areaCode}) ${ext}`;
  }

  private render(value) {
    const element = this.element.nativeElement;
    this.renderer.setProperty(element, 'value', value);
  }
}
```

Comment: it works nice, however if I edit a character in the middle is moving the cursor to the end.